# Does OpenCL work over Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, remote-desktop, opencl

I have heard conflicting things about the ability of OpenCL with GPU working over remote desktop.  Recently, I read that it can, if you have Windows 8 or greater?  Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

As per this, it is supported in Windows 10: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/01/11/remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-10-avch-264-improvements-in-windows-10-and-windows-server-2016-technical-preview/

> For example, with Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview we now enable OpenGL applications with RemoteFX vGPU scenarios which enables support for additional high-end engineering design applications that use OpenGL.

Comment: it seems like the question is about OpenCL, and you've answered with regards to OpenGL.

Comment: Good point - this article https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/10/07/whats-new-in-remote-desktop-services-for-the-next-version-of-windows-server/ - says that Server 2016 supports Remote Desktop + OpenCL 1.1. This was not available in previous versions of windows (e.g.: Win 8).